# Prevent Java application from accessing/monitoring/altering clipboard contents

Tags: windows-7, java

I'm a student using a service that provides practice questions for standardized tests. The service requires that I access the questions by downloading and running a Java application.

If I try to copy anything from any window of my computer (including applications unrelated to the question bank) while the application is running, the copied item is replaced with an obnoxious message asking me to not pirate their copyrighted material.

I find this obnoxious, and I also really don't like the idea that any application can slurp up any and all potentially sensitive information that I happen to copy while it's running.

Is there are a way to limit the privileges of this application to stop it from doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: I've tried looking all over for ways of controlling Java permissions, and I've tried an external program called "ClipX" that gives my clipboard history, but doesn't seem to work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotKey comes to my mind. You *probably* make a short script that makes a "alternate-clipboard" where say win+c copies and win+v pastes. Then of course this obnoxious crappy app would not have access. start here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=2665